# BTRFS zero log, now can't find any recent files

Tags: linux, hard-drive, btrfs

I recently physically relocated my Pi + BTRFS array (let's say /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, set up as a mirror) and was struggling to get the subvolume to mount properly again. Amongst the many things I tried, I saw one suggestion to use btrfs-zero-log. I didn't see any warnings of "this may cause you to lose data" or anything, and a quick search around didn't suggest this was a dangerous command (though perhaps unnecessary these days), so I gave it a shot on /dev/sda. It didn't fix my problem, but eventually I got things to work and got the subvolume remounted.

When I started looking through my folder, however, I found that all file changes since ~6 months ago had vanished. Folders and files no longer existed. I had the files I'd initially cloned from an old, failed drive, but nothing newer than that. When I ran `btrfs scrub`, it said that basically every block on the other drive, /dev/sdb, was corrupt and needed to be fixed.

I've tried mounting each drive independently in degraded mode to see if one of them still had the newer data, but no luck, at this point they both show only the old data. Is this something that my zero-log command might've caused? Is there any way to recover the new files/folders from /dev/sdb at this point, since it seems like the hashes and folders have been "fixed" from /dev/sda? Please help, I do have some backups, but it seems ridiculous to have to start over from those when I have a mirror of two perfectly good drives.